# Matching and sorting data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a form that collects data from people and dumps it into a google spreadsheet. On The spreadsheet I am trying to create a table that arranges this data so its easier for myself and other people to understand. 
Here is a sample of generally what the data is like.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iFKUg9vu_kdYe5Se0Fc6I9wcJp5NLXHvCA41CtTuFhc/edit?usp=sharing

On the sheet called "Form" this is where the data is dumped from the google form. On the sheet called "Table" is where I am trying to sort the information. Each row is the name of a person and each of the columns are different car brands.

I am trying to have it so the cells on the "table" sheet will look for a match from the "form" sheet and have it fill in the proper rating for that brand of car that each person recorded. If the person had 2 of the same brand cars is it also possible to put both ratings in the same column on the "table" sheet?

I was trying to use the built-in MATCH function but I couldn't figure out how to make it return the values of the rating column beside the brand if it found a match. I am still a beginner when it comes to combining different functions and was wondering if anyone could help me out. Is it possible to do this with the built in functions or only with a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you allow for multiple matches (as in `9,10` example), I recommend using `filter` and `join`. Here is my formula, written for the cell B3 but copy-pasteable to other cells in the table:

```
=iferror(join(",", filter(filter(Form!$C:$I, Form!$A:$A = $A3), filter(Form!$B:$H, Form!$A:$A = $A3) = B$2)))
```

Explanation:

1. `filter(Form!$B:$H, Form!$A:$A = $A3)` takes columns B-H for the user with name specified in A3
2. `filter(Form!$C:$I, Form!$A:$A = $A3)` does the same but for columns C-I range shifted to the right by one cell compared to the previous filter.
3. Then, yet another `filter` picks from the second range the cells where the corresponding entry of the first range is the car model in B2. This amounts to taking the cells that are immediately to the right of the model designation.
4. If there is more than one match, the results are `join`ed in a string, delimited by commas.
5. If there is no match, the filter throws #N/A error; this is suppressed by `iferror` so the cell stays blank.

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually didn't think about using filter and join before. I really appreciate you writing an explanation of what each part of the code does so that its easier for me to learn. Thanks again and happy holidays :).